# Query failed where runnig bigger time period (mssql server 2005 under php only)

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have a weird problem.

I'm running a query:

```sql
SELECT IMIE, NAZWISKO, PESEL2, ADD_DATE, CONVERT(varchar, ADD_DATE, 121) AS XDATA, ID_ZLECENIA_XXX, * FROM XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA AS EKH1
INNER JOIN XXX_DANE_PACJENTA EDP1 ON EKH1.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX=EDP1.ORDER_ID_XXX
WHERE EKH1.ID_KONWERSJE = (
    SELECT MIN(ID_KONWERSJE)
    FROM XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA AS EKH2
    WHERE EKH1.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX = EKH2.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX
)
AND EDP1.RECNO = ( 
    SELECT MAX(RECNO) 
    FROM XXX_DANE_PACJENTA EDP2
    WHERE EDP2.ORDER_ID_XXX = EDP1.ORDER_ID_XXX
)
AND EKH1.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX LIKE '%140000393%'
AND ADD_DATE>'20140419' AND ADD_DATE<='20140621 23:59:59.999' 
ORDER BY EKH1.ID_KONWERSJE, EKH1.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX DESC
```

And the query works ok if I use a date limit around 2 months (63 days - it gives me 1015 results). If I extend the date limit query simply fails (Query failed blabla).

This happens under windows 64 bit php (apache, Xamp).

When I run this query directly from MS SQL SERWER Management Studio everything works fine, no matter what date limit I choose.

What is going on? Is there a limit of some kind under apache/php? (There is no information like "query time excessed", only "query failed")

Comment: add set_time_limit(0); at the start of your php page where query is running

Comment: It did not help. I already use ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000); but there is nothing about exceding time, only "query failed"

Comment: did you tried mssql_get_last_message()

Comment: The *blabla* in *Query failed blabla* is most of the time important.

Comment: mssql_get_last_message() returns: Changed database context to 'DatabaseName'.  juergen d here is full message:  mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in H:\xampp\htdocs\script\index.php on line 141

Comment: @baron_bartek: Please publish the actual execution plan in XML format.

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlea - not sure how to do it in this querry. I will find info on the internet, and post results.

Comment: @baron_bartek: Execute this query in SSMS thus: Ctrl + M > F5 > Click on Execution Plan tab > open contextual menu > Save as XML ...

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlea - here is the screen of the plan http://strimatex.nazwa.pl/maxium/execute_plan.jpg and here is the xml http://strimatex.nazwa.pl/maxium/execute_plan.sqlplan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And the query works ok if I use a date limit around 2 months (63 days
>   - it gives me 1015 results). If I extend the date limit query simply fails (Query failed blabla). ... 
>   What is going on? Is there a limit of
>   some kind under apache/php? (There is no information like "query time
>   excessed", only "query failed")

This could happen because selectivity of `ADD_DATE>'20140419' AND ADD_DATE<='20140621 23:59:59.999'` is medium/low (there are [too] many rows that satisfy this predicate) and SQL Server have to scan (yes, scan) `XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA` to many times to check following predicate:

```
WHERE EKH1.ID_KONWERSJE = (
    SELECT ...
    FROM XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA AS EKH2
    WHERE EKH1.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX = EKH2.ID_ZLECENIA_XXX
)
```

How many times have to scan SQL Server `XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA` table to verify this predicate ? You can look at the properties of `Table Scan [XXX_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA]` data access operator: 3917 times
[image]

What you can do for the beginning ? You should create the missing index (see that warning with green above the execution plan):

```
USE [OptimedMain]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[ERLAB_KONWERSJE_HISTORIA] ([ID_ZLECENIA_ERLAB])
INCLUDE ([ID_KONWERSJE])
GO
```

> When I run this query directly from MS SQL SERWER Management Studio
>   everything works fine, no matter what date limit I choose.

SQL Server Management Studio has execution timeout set to 0 by default (no execution timeout).

Note: if this index will solve the problem then you should try (1) to create an index on `ADD_DATE` with all required (`CREATE INDEX ... INCLUDE(...)`) columns and (2) to create unique clustered indexes on these tables.

Comment: This is really solid answer. Thank you. I will check this out, and create proper indexes. There is also plan B - I created new table in database where I will store some new data, so this complicated query will not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set these php configurations in your php script via [ini_set](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('mssql.timeout', 60 * 20);
```

Not sure it will help you out.

Comment: Setting mssql.timeout changes the execution limit for any given SQL command initiated via PHP (I think the default is 30 seconds). When running in SMSS there is no limit for a sql command. If running in a hosted environment, caller may not be able to actually change this setting due to an administrative restriction.

Comment: default via php its 60 seconds. Yes you are correct.

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); - this is good idea. I tried once and the script was working, and working, and working... till I got information (from browser) about connection limit (serwer is not responding too long). I will try to do more tests with smaller memory limit.

Comment: More testing: in general increasing memory limit is giving back "serwer is not responding too long". Maybe it's my apache fault? Or maybe its mssql serwer problem, becouse I managed to block it once with this query - it was simply not possible to connect until restart.